# What is Pipe number ( | number ) in the deleteHero method of hero.service.ts in Angular v5 Tour of Heroes Tutorial

Tags: javascript, angular, methods, angular-services

Javascript / Typscript is new to me.
As i work through the Angular Tour of Heros, I keep seeing syntax I have not seen in my C# programming.

In the Tour of Heroes  Angular v5 tutorial, there is some javascript syntax I can't understand.

Can someone help me understand what the "| number" is in the deleteHero method definition?

Ref: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroservicedeletehero

```
    /** DELETE: delete the hero from the server */
deleteHero (hero: Hero | number): Observable<Hero> {
  const id = typeof hero === 'number' ? hero : hero.id;
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;

  return this.http.delete<Hero>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`deleted hero id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('deleteHero'))
  );
}
```

Comment: That's Typescript, not Javascript. It means the type is either a number or Hero.

Comment: @Sébastien This question is not about angular pipes.

Comment: Sorry about that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a union type. You can read about [union types in typescript here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

Basically `hero: Hero | number` means that the parameter named `hero` can be of type `Hero` OR of type `number`, and the function will work with either.